# Java Beans with dynamic identifications

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file with equal no of tokens ( random sometimes) per page.
I need to create java beans to store /retrieve each token.

Problem :
If the CSV file has 3 cols then i need the java bean with 3 cols to store /retrieve.

ex : - public void setCol3(String col1,String col2,String col3){
         .....
       }

If the CSV file has 6 cols then i need the java bean with 6 cols to store /retrieve.

ex : - public void setCol6(String col1,String col2,String col3,
                              String col4,String col5,String col6){
         .....
       }

Question:
Is there any way in Java Beans to Automatically assign as per the no of tokens (columns) of the CSV

with regards
karthik

Comment: Just store a row's values in a List<String>.

Comment: Hi  I  know how to handle the rows values.... but this is NOT i am intrested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a flexible bean which can have different number of properties. I wrote a java class named [FlexBean](https://github.com/ramazanpolat/flexbean) for this particular reason.

With FlexBean, you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    printCSVLines(readCSV("c:/deleteme/sample.csv"));

}

public static List<FlexBean> readCSV(String csvFile){
    List<FlexBean> csvLines = new ArrayList<>();

    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            FlexBean csvLine = new FlexBean();
            for (int i=0;i<country.length;i++){
                csvLine.set("col"+i, country[i]);
            }
            csvLines.add(csvLine);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return csvLines;
}

public static void printCSVLine(FlexBean csvLine){
    for (String col: csvLine.getPropertyNames()){
        System.out.print(csvLine.valueOf(col).toString()+" | ");
    }
}

public static void printCSVLines(List<FlexBean> csvLines){
    for (FlexBean line: csvLines) {
        printCSVLine(line);
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```